# Qt QML application crashes when QList objects in context property are deleted

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have QML ListView with some model (which are `QList<QObject*>`) provided by context property:

```
g->appEngine->rootContext()->setContextProperty("queueStatesModel", QVariant::fromValue(this->queueStates));
```

Everything going well until I'm trying to clear the ListView. I'm doing this like that:

```
qDeleteAll(this->queueStates);
this->queueStates.clear();
```

and then again I'm setting context property with empty QList, which causing application crash. When I'm doing the same without deleting all objects with qDeleteAll everything going well, ListView is clear, application not crashing, but objects remains and I'm loosing pointers to them.

What's could be wrong with that?

Comment: I guess it's wrong idea to recreate the list to only clear the view. You have to operate with the queue data instead. The best way is to implement custom QAbstractItemModel  model.

Comment: @folibis Thank you for your reply. I know what you're thinking about, but documentation says: "There is no way for the view to know that the contents of a QList has changed. If the QList changes, it is necessary to **reset the model by calling QQmlContext::setContextProperty() again**." so if there is such possibility, I thought there is nothing wrong with delete objects and reset context property to clear the view.

Comment: Maybe, maybe ... but you see that this approach cause to problems. What for example should happen between clearing the list and resetting the property? What if `ListView` will repaint its contect in this time and will call to queueStatesModel.at(1), for example?

Comment: @folibis You are absolutely right, but in my case it may be little overstatement to implement QAbstractItemModel , for now QList it's enough - data source is SOAP API and I don't need to refreshing objects, I need to display them only once, during request. I've found a solution, I will write below.

Answer (score 0):

I've found some solution - not very elegant but working.

Before `QList::clear()` I do copy of pointers from that list to another QList. Then I `clear()` first list and set context property. After that I perform `qDeleteAll` and `clear()` at second list. More or less like this:

```
this->queueStatesCache = this->queueStates;
this->queueStates.clear();
g->appEngine->rootContext()->setContextProperty("queueStatesModel", QVariant::fromValue(this->queueStates));
qDeleteAll(this->queueStatesCache);
this->queueStatesCache.clear();
```